# Is there a way to check universal link registration from Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links

iOS has a universal link capability (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

However, it looks like there are couple of ways to "disassociate" a link from the application:

- Press and hold on a link and choose "Open in Safari"
- There was a tiny link in the top right corner of the app, which was shown right after opening universal link (it looks like it's gone in iOS 11).

As soon as you did one of these actions then universal link will be opened in Safari (until you reassociate it back to the app).

The issue is that if a user end up in this state, it's not clear what he/she should do. I want to provide an explanation on the web page which will be opened in Safari.

However, I want to distinguish two cases:

- A link is clicked on a device without the app: Tell a user to download the app
- A link is clicked on a device where the app is installed and it's disassociated. Tell a user how to associate it back.

Is there a way to check whether universal link is registered from a page opened in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that iOS 11 took away the upper-right hand corner button to re-enable universal links. They have kept the banner that shows up when you scroll the page up slightly.

[image]

This banner acts will also re-enable Universal Links for the user.

Unfortunately, there is no perfect solution to determining if a user has the app installed, but there are a few ways to attempt to deduce whether the user has the app installed already. [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking) has ways of deducing whether the user has the app installed and attempting to open it with a URI scheme. You can read about the `$uri_redirect_mode` in the [docs](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#forced-redirections).

It would be very difficult to build this deducing method on your own and I'm not entirely sure how it's done, so I recommend using Branch's solution.